# Error using DLast and DateDiff to calculate an interval between two time values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been using the code below to create a time interval between two entries to be shown on a report.

The problem I'm having is an error is being thrown somewhere and the interval remains at its default value of 99999.

I set LValue to 99999 so I could see when this error occurred because a lot of other people are using my database and intervals tend to be between 30-50 minutes.

The only way I've been able to replicate it myself is when I copy data from another table in another database into the "Daily Oven/Product Record" table. The most recent error occurred when someone accidentally moved the backend database from its folder and back again.

Is there a problem with my code or something else I'm not looking at?

```
LValue = 99999
On Error GoTo catchInterval
        Dim ovenTimeInterval As Variant
        Dim strChangeover As String

    If boolChangeover = True Then
        strChangeover = " (C/O)"
    Else
        strChangeover = ""
    End If

    'Find last Process No entered
    ovenTimeInterval = DLast("[Time]", "Daily Oven/Product Record")

    'DateDiff 
    LValue = datediff("n", ovenTimeInterval, Now())
catchInterval:

[Time Interval] = LValue & strChangeover
```

Comment: Please tell us more about the error condition: the full text of the error message; and which line of that code triggers it.

Comment: @Adam44 get rid of your `On Error` condition and run the code to check for run-time errors.